# Tablesorter - filter-select and filter_saveFilters

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a table with filters rendered as select boxes and the option that the filter is saved between page reloads. Works so far. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
<script>
$('.tablesorter').tablesorter({
    widgets: ["saveSort", "filter", "zebra"],
    widgetOptions: {
        filter_saveFilters : true,
        saveSort: true
    }
});
</script>

<table class="table tablesorter" data-sortlist="[[1,0]]">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-filter="false" data-sort="false">Image</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="filter-select">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> ... </tbody>
</table>
```

Here comes the problem: First page load - filter status for "error" (select-box) results in one table row displayed. Then I fix the error and reload the page. Now all rows are filtered out, but the status filter select-box is empty (does not contain the active filter "error", thus displays an empty string).

**That means that the displayed filter and the displayed table rows do not match, which is a problem.**

When I activly select the empty value in the status filter, all rows get displayed again.

Any ideas how to handle this issue? Thanks for your solutions :)